# Access Popup-Dialog inside a data template

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp, uwp-xaml, template10

[image: UI of Saavn App]

I have just started learning windows app development. Like what do we call it     (A dialog box, Contentdialogbox, Message Dialog)? Thanks in advance.

Okay I tried this since I have my data in a datatemplate inside a contentpresenter(Making a master detail view)  now when user clicks on a icon the popup should open and also display the data related to that event selected inside that list.How do I achieve this since the popup dialog control is defined inside a datatemplate so  in my cs file it does not recognize the control so I am not able to open the popup dialog.

Xaml Code:

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="DetailContentTemplate" x:DataType="data:Event">
        <Grid>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="200" />
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />

            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid x:Name="Section2" Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/8.JPG" Stretch="Fill" />
                </Grid.Background>


                <TextBlock MaxWidth="250"
                           Margin="36,62,34,68"
                           FontFamily="Baskerville Old Face"
                           FontSize="30"
                           Foreground="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"
                           TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                           d:LayoutOverrides="Width, LeftPosition, RightPosition, TopPosition, BottomPosition">
                    <Run Text="Gravitas Premier League" />

                </TextBlock>

            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="Content"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                    <RelativePanel>
                        <SymbolIcon x:Name="symbol"
                                    Margin="0,0,5,0"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                                    Symbol="Globe" />

                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                   RelativePanel.RightOf="symbol"
                                   Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
                                   Text="Category" />
                    </RelativePanel>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <RelativePanel>
                        <SymbolIcon x:Name="symboll"
                                    Margin="0,0,5,0"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                                    Symbol="People" />

                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                   RelativePanel.RightOf="symboll"
                                   Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
                                   Text="SubCategory" />
                    </RelativePanel>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <RelativePanel>
                        <SymbolIcon x:Name="symbllol"
                                    Margin="0,0,5,0"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                                    Symbol="Bullets" />

                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                   RelativePanel.RightOf="symbllol"
                                   Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
                                   Text="Rupee" />
                    </RelativePanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       Style="{ThemeResource ScenarioDescriptionTextStyle}"
                       Text="{x:Bind description}"
                       TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" />

            <Grid Grid.Row="3">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                <SymbolIcon Grid.Column="0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Symbol="Phone" />
                <SymbolIcon Grid.Column="1"
                            x:Name="People"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Symbol="People"
                            IsTapEnabled="True"
                            Tapped="ShowPopupOffsetClicked"
                            />



                <SymbolIcon Grid.Column="2"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Symbol="Mail" />

            </Grid>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Now how do I open up the popup when the user taps the symbol with the name People and with necessary bindings of data with a observablecollection say EventList.

Comment: Should be an [ContentDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.aspx)

Comment: Any idea how do I get a content dialog  like in the image?Thanks

Comment: Well, since nobody knows what your Application does and what you have tried, you will have to make your own one

Comment: I would probably just have a Popup with a StackPanel. I don't think you explicitly need a dialog.

Comment: Hey I added my code?can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to implement the UI like in your screenshot. As you've added [template10](/questions/tagged/template10) in your question, I suppose you are using [Template10](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10) in your project. And in Template10, we can use [**ModalDialog**](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki/Docs-%7C-Controls#modaldialog) to implement this. Here I use a Minimal Template 10 project for example.

Firstly, we may need to change `ModalBackground` to make the background color looks like what in your screenshot. As the `ModalDialog` we used here is the root frame created by `Bootstrapper` automatically, so we need override `CreateRootElement` in App.xaml.cs like:

```
public override UIElement CreateRootElement(IActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    var b = Current;
    var frame = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame();
    var nav = b.NavigationServiceFactory(BackButton.Attach, ExistingContent.Include, frame);

    //change background
    var background = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Gray);
    background.Opacity = 0.2;

    return new Template10.Controls.ModalDialog
    {
        ModalBackground = background,
        DisableBackButtonWhenModal = true,
        Content = nav.Frame
    };
}
```

Then we can edit Busy.xaml to implement the panel in your screenshot. In Busy.xaml, it's a `UserControl` used as the `ModalContent` of `ModalDialog`. For example,

```
<UserControl x:Class="T10Minimal.Views.Busy"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="using:T10Minimal.Views"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="400"
             mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Width="300"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Background="White"
          CornerRadius="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            ...
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Margin="20,0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="24"
                   Foreground="Black">
            Song Options
        </TextBlock>
        <Button Margin="12"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Click="CloseClicked"
                Foreground="Black"
                Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}">
            <SymbolIcon Symbol="Clear" />
        </Button>
        ...
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The bindings might like the `BusyText` in the original control, you can change its type to your binding data's type and also change the `SetBusy` method. After this, you can call `SetBusy` method in your `ShowPopupOffsetClicked` method to open the "popup".

This is just a simple sample, you can refer to it to implement your own. And in the sample, I used the `ModalDialog` created as the root frame of the application. If you need more than one `ModalDialog`, you can refer to [Search (and Login) Sample](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/tree/master/Samples/Search) on GitHub.

Comment: Hey thanks I got everything worked out by using pop up dialog  but I am not able to get the separating lines like in the UI .Can you help(I have used appbarseparator also).Thanks again!

Comment: @shubh The separating lines in the UI is not `AppBarSeparator`.   [AppBarSeparator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbarseparator.aspx) is used in an `AppBar` or `CommandBar`. I guess the separating lines you've seen is a [Border](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.border.aspx) like `<Border Background="#FFE2E2E2" Height="1" Margin="15,0" />`.